# How Route 53 servers get into the DNS resolver chain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am using the following typical DNS resolution procedure as a reference to my question toward using AWS Route 53 as the DNS server(s).

[image]

Let's say, I registered example1.com with Route53 and use it as my DNS service and I registered example2.com with Godaddy and use Godaddy DNS service.

From the above diagram, it seems to me that DNS servers being contacted/reached before Step 4 would be identical. My question is how would the .COM server be able to return Route53 servers as the DNS server list for example1.com, and return Godaddy servers as the DNS server list for example2.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because your DNS servers are registered with your domain.

If you make a `whois domain.com` on a domain or a `dig domain.com NS` you will see which dns servers are registered